# Unable to perform POST request with fetch in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch, json-server

I am attempting to perform a POST operation on a json file being served by a json-server in node. I am receiving the following 500 error when attempting to perform said POST operation:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Function.createId"

The post operation is as follows:

```
pushState = () => {
        var update = {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2
        };

    return fetch(url, {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(update)
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      response.text();
    })
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log("Response:",responseData);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .done();
  }
```

Am I impementing the POST request correctly?

**Edit:** After adding async and await I'm still getting the same error:

```
pushState = async () => {
  var update = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  };

  var result = await fetch(url, {
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(update)
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I think it might be a server issue, try passing an id with update? `var update = { id: 1, a: 1, b: 2 };`

Comment: Adding and ID field worked! Is there a reason the id field is required? What if the API i am calling doesn't have an id field, or has a differently named ID field?

Comment: I believe its just because you're using json-server and the way that is set up is to look for an id, which is why it said "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at Function.createId". Not all API's will require id's but its good practice to use id's to keep track of data better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. You are not returning anything from `fetch`.
2. `fetch` is asynchronous. With the way you are calling it now with `pushState` returning a result immediately, it will almost always return `undefined` as you are getting in your error. You need write `pushState` using async/await.

Edit to answer comments:

Since you are using the function arrow syntax, making `pushState` asynchronous would look like this:

```
pushState = async () => { /* code */ }
```

To help you understand how `fetch` works, I recommend reading [this first](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch). Then to understand async/await at a high level, read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9). Your resulting code will look something like this:

```
pushState = async () => {
  var update = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  };

  var result = await fetch(...) // Remember to return something.

  return result;
}
```

Comment: So I'd make it "async pushState()", correct? And how would I use await?

Comment: @BillyBobJoel Edited to hopefully answer your questions.

Comment: I've added the updated code. I'm still getting the same error. Could the problem be the way I'm serving the json file?

Comment: @BillyBobJoel Maybe. Could be what Matt Aft suggests. What is the `url` you are posting to and what does your json-server db look like?